# How to draw a conical spiral / redraw diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to redraw the diagram diagram below.  I'm using it as an exemplar/reference in a document I am writing but I need it to be clearer hence the redraw.

[image: Diagram/Spiral]

I tried and failed to draw it in Inkscape.  After thinking about it for a while though, I thought actually it could be done (and perhaps better) mathematically using something like Tikz.  I've looked through the questions here and I can find [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133183/draw-spiral-cone-tikz) but not what I need.

So far, my code is a just a pathetic cloud and an oval and missing the crucial 2D spiral cone:

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [cloud, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, aspect=2, inner ysep=1em,text width=1cm]{Needs\\and\\Ideas};
\draw  (0,-10) ellipse (4 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `(point a) to [in=degree,out=degree,looseness=value]` to draw bent lines. I used two sets of those, computing the coordinates in a loop. Afterwards, another loop is used to set the descriptions. This answer uses **Caramdir**'s solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,shapes}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,7}
{   \draw[decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.8+\x/60 with {\arrow{latex}}},postaction=decorate] (1+\x/5,-1-\x) to [out=90,in=90,looseness=0.5] (-1-\x/5,-1-\x) node[xshift=-0.05cm] (gate-\x) {\footnotesize stage gate};
    \draw (1+\x/5,-1-\x) to [out=270,in=270,looseness=0.5] (-0.8-\x/5,-\x);
}
\foreach \gate [count=\c] in {asdf,sdfg sdfg,dfgh dfgh dfgh,fghj fghj,ghjk,hjkl hjkl hjkl,TeX TeX TeX TeX}
{ \node[text width=2cm, align=right,left=1cm] at (gate-\c) {\gate};
}
\draw (-2.4,-8) to [out=270, in =120] (-1.5,-9);

\node [cloud, draw,cloud puffs=10,cloud puff arc=120, aspect=2, inner ysep=1em,text width=1cm,fill=white]{Needs\\and\\Ideas};
\draw[fill=white]  (0,-10) ellipse (4 and 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]