# pstricks spiral with labels

Tags: pstricks, graphs

I am trying to recreate the following spiral graphic using **pstricks**:

[image]

which should look like

[image]

My first thought was to use a logarithmic function like in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209185/152963).
But then I wouldn't know how to add the labels.

Another thougt would be to use `\pscurve`. Maybe someone knows how I can find out the points of the graphic to use that function.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Your question is not clear: is it supposed to be a *helix*  (i.e.  a skew curve in $3$-space) or a *spiral* ( a plane curve, usually defined by a polar equation, like Archimedes' spiral)?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your suggestion to make the question more clear. I added a picture which hopefully shows my intention

Comment: Suggestion: Rephrase your title using **spiral** instead of **helix**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small variant, with Archimedes' spiral:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdf, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[f]{esvect}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-math, pst-func}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX)

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\psset{plotpoints=200, labelsep=1ex}
\everypsbox{\sffamily}
\psplot[polarplot, arrows=*-, linecolor=Tomato, linewidth=1.2pt, dotsize=2.5pt,]{0}{440}{x 100 div}
\multido{\i = 180 + 40, \n = 1.8 + 0.4}{7}{\uput[\i](\n; \i){A\i}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I guess that is the easier and cleaner way of creating a spiral. Therefore I accepted your answer as the "best" one.

Comment: There's just a problem: I tried a logarithmic spiral, but it didn't work (I can plot functions with logarithms, but strangely it doesn't work for polar plots). Any way, the way the curves  begin are not very different, but I think I'll have to post a question.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(5,5)
\psparametricplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,plotpoints=1000]{0}{-510}%
  {t sin t DegtoRad 2 div mul t cos t DegtoRad 2 div mul }
\multido{\iA=180+40,\rA=-3.14+-0.698}{7}{%
    \rput*(! \rA\space neg dup RadtoDeg cos 1.5 div mul  
    \rA\space dup RadtoDeg sin 1.6 div mul){A$\iA$}}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks perfect for my purpose! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Since some nice PStricks answers have already be posted, as requested by the OP, I felt free to post the same kind of figure, this time with MetaPost, for whom it may interest. Code included in a LuaLaTeX program thanks to the `luamplib` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
u := cm;
path spirale;
beginfig(1);
  spirale = origin
    for t = 1 upto 420:
        hide(pair currentpoint; currentpoint = u*t/90*dir t;
                if (t >= 180) and ((t-180) mod 40 = 0):
                    freelabel("A" & decimal t, currentpoint, origin); fi)
        .. currentpoint
    endfor;
  draw spirale withcolor red;
endfig; 
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]